# graphviz,pythonでdot言語のedgeのlabelの使い方を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, dot, graphviz

edgeのlabel "A to 1" にしたい。
よろしくお願いします。

```
def apply_styles(graph, styles):
    graph.edge_attr.update(
        ('edges' in styles and styles['edges']) or {}
    )
    return graph
from graphviz import Digraph
g = Digraph('G', filename='cluster.gv')
with g.subgraph(name='cluster_1') as c:
    # c.edges([('1', 'A [label=A to 1]'),
    c.edges([('1', 'A'),
             ('1', 'B')
             ])
    styles = {
        'edges': {
             'dir': 'both',
             'arrowhead': 'none',
             'arrowtail': 'normal'
            }
       }
    c = apply_styles(c, styles)
g.view()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/blob/7a82498092454f1c9a4cdb4a85f96fad5707827f/graphviz/dot.py#L143
この辺の実装を見てもらうと、残念なことにedges()でlabelをつける方法がないことがわかります。

```
c.edge('1', 'A', label='A to 1')
```

と1つずつlabelを付けてやってください。

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntaxがでました。

Comment: 間違えました。動きました。

Answer (score 1):

```
c.edges([('1', 'A [label=A to 1]'),
```

を

```
c.edges([('1', 'A', label='A to 1'),
```

にすれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntaxがでました。